# Using getopts in bash to get optional input argument

Tags: bash, shell, getopt, getopts

I am using getopts  to process the input arguments. I have problem in reading optional argument value.
When I invoke the script with arguments `test.sh -t test -r server -p password -v 1`
`$OPTARG` is not returning the value of the optional argument `-v`.

Can anyone let me know how to process the optional argument value?

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() 
{
cat << EOF
usage: $0 options

OPTIONS:
   -h      Show this message
   -t      Test type
   -r      Server address
   -p      Server root password
   -v      Verbose
EOF
}

TEST=
SERVER=
PASSWD=
VERBOSE=

echo "======111======"
while getopts "ht:r:p:v" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         h)
             usage
             echo "===Option h selected=="
             exit 1
             ;;
         t)
             TEST=$OPTARG
             echo "====option t selected===$TEST"
             ;;
         r)
             SERVER=$OPTARG
             echo "=====option r selected==="
             ;;
         p)
             PASSWD=$OPTARG
             echo "====option p selected==="
             ;;
         v)
             VERBOSE=$OPTARG
             echo "======option v selected===$VERBOSE"
             ;;
         ?)
             echo "====unknown option selected===="
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done

echo "========222===="
```

Comment: I believe you are missing a colon `:` after the `v` in the `getopts` call. It should be `while getopts "ht:r:p:v:"`.

Comment: Alternatively you could just write something like `((VERBOSE++))` and avoid an argument altogether

Answer (score 0):

1. Do the thing in the case statement.

   ```
   case $OPTION in
     v)
       VERBOSE=$OPTARG
       do_the_thing $OPTARG
       ;;
   esac
   ```
2. Do the thing after the case statement.

   ```
   if [ ! -z "$VERBOSE" ]; then
     do_the_thing "$VERBOSE"
   else
     do_not_do_the_thing
   fi
   ```